# How to compute $P(X = Y )$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X \sim Bin(n,p)$, $Y \sim Bin(m,q)$ be independent random variables.
Now I want to compute $P(X=Y)$.

We have

$P(X=Y) = P^{(X,Y)}(\{(x,y) : x=y\}) = \int \mathbb{1}_{\{(x,y) : x=y\}} (x,y) P^{(X,Y)}(d(x,y))$ $ = \int \int \mathbb{1}_{\{y\}}(x) P^X(dx) P^Y(dy) = \int P(X = y) P^Y(dy) = \int \binom{n}{y} p^y(1-p)^{n-y}P^Y(dy)$.

How can I calculate the last integral? Is it even possible to calculate it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since $X$ and $Y$ are discrete, we can replace the integral by a sum, and Wolfram Alpha gives [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5En+%5Cfrac%7Bn%21%7D%7Bk%21%28n-k%29%21%7D%5Cfrac%7Bm%21%7D%7Bk%21%28m-k%29%21%7Dp%5Ek+q%5Ek+%281-p%29%5E%7Bn-k%7D%281-q%29%5E%7Bm-k%7D ) as answer, which consists of the Hypergeometric Function.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit?

Answer (score 1):

Assume without loss of generality that $n \le m$.
Then we want to compute $\mathbb{P}(X=Y)$.
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}(X=Y) &=& \mathbb{P}( \bigcup_{k=0}^n X = k \textrm{ and } Y=k) &X \in \{0, \dots n \}\\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^n \mathbb{P}(X=k \textrm{ and } Y =k) \\
&=&\sum_{k=0}^n\mathbb{P}(X=k) \mathbb{P}(Y=k) &X \textrm{ and } Y \textrm{ are independent}\\
&=& \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \binom{m}{k} q^k (1-q)^{m-k} 
\end{eqnarray}
However, I do not see a nice way to compute the last sum for arbitrary $m$, $n$, $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I got the same result, but how do I recieve this result from my integral?

Comment: Since $X$ and $Y$ are discrete, your integral is a sum over $\mathbb{N}$ with respect to the measure of $P^Y(y) = \binom{m}{y} q^y (1-q)^{m-y}$ for $y \le m$ and $P^Y(y) = 0$ for all $y>m$.

Comment: I got it now, thanks.